# Передача параметров. JQuery. Синтаксис

Tags: jquery

```
send_gift_account('+data.giftId+','+user+');
```

Так передает нормально, `send_gift_account(2432,Вася Пупкин)`, но нужно, чтобы параметры были в одинарных ковычках `send_gift_account('2432','Вася Пупкин')`

Пробую делать так:

```
send_gift_account('\'+data.giftId+\'','\'+user+\'');
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Потому что надо подумать сначала, а потом эскейпить. Первый же блок эскейпит вторую кавычку, а зачем?

Comment: Поправил код. Но это тоже не решает проблему

Comment: Вероятно не так поправили?

Comment: Посмотрите в вопросе. Что не так?

Comment: @ДенисНебесный приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Сейчас если написать `console.log('\'+data.giftId+\'', '\'+user+\'');`, в консоль будет выдано `'+data.giftId+'` и `'+user+'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
send_gift_account(\'' + data.giftId + '\', \'' + user + '\');
```

Comment: `\''` - это ж синтаксическая ошибка, разве нет?

Comment: Код работает. В консоле ошибки нет. Всё нормально.

Comment: @Regent вообще да, но судя по вопросу автор просто выводит некую строку которую собирает на лету.

Answer (score -3):

Попробуйте использовать двойные кавычки, вот так:

```
send_gift_account("\'+data.giftId+\'", "\'+user+\'");
```